# Jitsi Meet - event for user muted by other participant in the meeting

Tags: vue.js, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I have requirement to show custom notification, if the user is muted by other participant in the meeting.

I have used [audiomutestatuschanged](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-iframe-events/#audiomutestatuschanged) event, It is detected when user mutes/unmutes himself but it is not detected when muted by someone else in the meeting.

any other hacks to implement this.

Good day. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in this cases when you need to do some custom stuff you can use the commands, of course you need to create a specific command for the muted/ unmuted and then just you can pass the props you need like info about who is trying to mute another participant. With the command listener of your command, with the data that you've received now you can use it to do whatever you need

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).